# pool соединений(JDBC) с базой данных mySQL из GlassFish 4.1.2

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

При ping-е соединения выходит ошибка:

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for mySQLpool. Class name is wrong or classpath 
is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check 
the server.log for more details.
```

Драйвер закидывал уже куда только можно. Никак.

Вот настройки соединения:

```
password        Password <br>
databaseName    library <br>
serverName      localhost <br>
user            root <br>
portNumber      3306 <br>
```

Не пингуется. Я не знаю что еще можно сделать.
Особо не ругайте, я ноль практически, только начинаю.

Comment: Второе предложение в сообщении об ошибке ни на какие мысли не наводит? `Class name is wrong or classpath 
is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check 
the server.log for more details.`

Comment: Посмотреть лог сервера? Вот что он выдает Warning:   RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ mySQLpool ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource

Comment: **Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource** Означает, что класс с именем _com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource_ не найден. По-английски совсем не читаете?

Comment: Понимаю. Но не понимаю как он может быть не найден. Куда надо его поместить, чтобы он был найден.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish не может найти ваш JDBC драйвер.
См. [NetBeans in the Classroom: MySQL JDBC Connection Pool & JDBC Resource for GlassFish](https://dzone.com/articles/nb-class-glassfish-mysql-jdbc) и [Setting the GlassFish JVM Classpath to the Database Drivers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0871/ug_wlmse-drivers_t/index.html)